# how to fetch limited data using api in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

Im able to fetch data using `retrofit` in android and able to set it view in `recyclerView` using adapter.but the thing is i don't want to fetch whole data from my api i want to remove some data from my api using java which should not be visible in recyclerview.

Android studio, java

```
private void getSearchProduct(String str_search_text, String page_no, String limit, final String catid) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (this);
    if (limit.equalsIgnoreCase ("")) {
        progressDialog.show ();
        progressDialog.setMessage ("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
    } else {
        progressDialog.setMessage ("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
    }
    if (page_no.equalsIgnoreCase ("")) {
        pagenonew = "";
    } else {
        pagenonew = page_no;
    }
    Log.e (TAG, "getSearchProduct: catid..............." + catid);
    if (catid.equals ("")) {
        category_id = catid;
        Log.e (TAG, "getSearchProduct: catid" + catid);
    }
    apiService = ApiUtils.getAPIService ();
    apiService.getSearchProduct ("" + latitude, "" + longitude, CustomerID, str_search_text, pagenonew, catid).enqueue (new Callback<Search_Product_Model> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Search_Product_Model> call, Response<Search_Product_Model> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful ()) {
                int status = response.body ().getStatus ();
                String meg = response.body ().getMsg ();
                if (status == 1) {
                    serach_product_lists.clear ();
                    serach_product_lists = response.body ().getProductList ();
                    /*  categoryID = response.body ().getCategory_id ();
                    Log.e (TAG, "categoryID: categoryID......" + categoryID);*/
                    Search_Product_Adapter adapter = new Search_Product_Adapter (SearchProduct_Fragment.this, serach_product_lists);
                    recycler_views_category_offerzone.setAdapter (adapter);
                    txt_noproduct.setVisibility (View.GONE);

                    recycler_views_category_offerzone.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    txt_noproduct.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                    txt_noproduct.setText (meg);
                    recycler_views_category_offerzone.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss ();
            } else {
                 progressDialog.dismiss ();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Search_Product_Model> call, Throwable t){
            progressDialog.dismiss ();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: remove extra elements from pojo files

Comment: Simply create a POJO class with the keys you require and remove all the keys that your don't require. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use RxJava in combination with Retrofit (they really work amazingly togheter) that has operator take which allows you to choose how many result to take

```
 Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
              .take(4)
              .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer item) {
                System.out.println("Next: " + item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
            }
        });
```

for more documentation please look at http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

for combining Retrofit and RxJAva 
https://www.journaldev.com/20433/android-rxjava-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask your service provider don't return the data you don't want to fetch.
2. Traverse your data list to find the data you don't want then remove them .As the following codes!

   `serach_product_lists = response.body ().getProductList ();
   for(data:serach_product_lists){
      if(//put your judge code here)
         serach_product_lists.remove(data)
   }`